# Elixir Supervisors — How do you name a Supervised Task

Tags: elixir, erlang-otp, erlang-supervisor

I'm really struggling with Elixir supervisors and figuring out how to name them so that I can use them. Basically, I'm just trying to start a supervised `Task` which I can send messages to.

So I have the following:

```
defmodule Run.Command do
  def start_link do
    Task.start_link(fn ->
      receive do
        {:run, cmd} -> System.cmd(cmd, [])
      end
    end)
  end
end
```

with the project entry point as:

```
defmodule Run do
  use Application

  # See http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Application.html
  # for more information on OTP Applications
  def start(_type, _args) do
    import Supervisor.Spec, warn: false

    children = [
      # Define workers and child supervisors to be supervised
      worker(Run.Command, [])
    ]

    # See http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Supervisor.html
    # for other strategies and supported options
    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: Run.Command]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end
end
```

At this point, I don't even feel confident that I'm using the right thing (`Task` specifically). Basically, all I want is to spawn a process or task or GenServer or whatever is right when the application starts that I can send messages to which will in essence do a `System.cmd(cmd, opts)`. I want this task or process to be supervised. When I send it a `{:run, cmd, opts}` message such as `{:run, "mv", ["/file/to/move", "/move/to/here"]}` I want it to spawn a new task or process to execute that command. For my use, I don't even need to ever get back the response from the task, I just need it to execute. Any guidance on where to go would be helpful. I've read through the getting started guide but honestly it left me more confused because when I try to do what is done it never turns out as it does in the application.

Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would just use a GenServer, set up like the following:

```
defmodule Run do
  use Application

  def start(_, _) do
    import Supervisor.Spec, warn: false

    children = [worker(Run.Command, [])]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, strategy: :one_for_one)
  end
end

defmodule Run.Command do
  use GenServer

  def start_link do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [], name: __MODULE__)
  end

  def run(cmd, opts) when is_list(opts), do: GenServer.call(__MODULE__, {:run, cmd, opts})
  def run(cmd, _), do: GenServer.call(__MODULE__, {:run, cmd, []})

  def handle_call({:run, cmd, opts}, _from, state) do
    {:reply, System.cmd(cmd, opts), state}
  end
  def handle_call(request, from, state), do: super(request, from, state)
end
```

You can then send the running process a command to execute like so:

```
# If you want the result
{contents, _} = Run.Command.run("cat", ["path/to/some/file"])
# If not, just ignore it
Run.Command.run("cp", ["path/to/source", "path/to/destination"])
```

Basically we're creating a "singleton" process (only one process can be registered with a given name, and we're registering the Run.Command process with the name of the module, so any consecutive calls to `start_link` while the process is running will fail. However, this makes it easy to set up an API (the `run` function) which can transparently execute the command in the other process without the calling process having to know anything about it. I used `call` vs. `cast` here, but it's a trivial change if you will never care about the result and don't want the calling process to block.

This is a better pattern for something long-running. For one-off things, `Task` is a lot simpler and easier to use, but I prefer to use `GenServer` for global processes like this personally.

Comment: That's a perfect solution. The reason why you can't name a Task is because if you want to send it messages... you don't want to use a Task anymore.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this in such detail. This was very helpful for me @bitwalker. Thank you for your time, assistance, and patience.

Comment: @bitwalker When trying to use this I get a GenServer.call timeout. Shouldn't the supervisor prevent this type of thing from happening? (exit) exited in: GenServer.call(Run.Command, {:run, "ls", ["."]}, 5000)
    ** (EXIT) time out
    (elixir) lib/gen_server.ex:356: GenServer.call/3

Comment: Ah, never mind. Cast is better for asynchronous situations where call is better for when a response is needed due to synchronous. Sorry!

Comment: @kkirsche The supervisor doesn't prevent timeouts, it just makes sure the process is restarted after a failure, so you can either set the timeout to a larger value when using `call` if you are making calls to long running commands, or use `cast` :)